# Why do Google Sheets and Excel give different exponential regressions?

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel

I have the following simple set of data:

```
xi  yi
1   2
2   1
3   4
4   6
5   6
6   10
```

When I draw it on a chart and then add the best exponential trendline, both in Google Sheets and Excel, I obtain two different equations and R2. Why?

Screenshot from Google Sheets:
[image]

Screenshot from Excel:
[image]

Comment: Well, obviously they use different algorithms to calculate the trendline. Maybe one uses the least squares method and the other one doesn't?

Comment: What do you mean by "add the best exponential trendline"? What steps do you followed on each app?

Comment: The question will be, which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

From https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/trendlines#exponential-trendlines

> Note: Unlike linear trendlines, there are several different ways to compute exponential trendlines. We provide only one method right now, but will support more in the future, and so it's possible that the name or behavior of the current exponential trendline will change.

The above is relevant to this questions because according to https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets

> Google Charts and Google Spreadsheets are tightly integrated. You can place a Google Chart inside a Google Spreadsheet, and Google Charts can extract data out of Google Spreadsheets. This documentation shows you how to do both.